# NodeJS: how disable auto output after every line in console?

Tags: node.js, console, output, command-line-interface

[image]

As u can see on the image, after every line, an automatic output appears. I want do disable this. I do not intend to use it as a workaround editor, the problem is that on some functions this output is more than some screens big and is hard to look at the expected result.

Comment: It's the return value of the function. _"and is hard to look at the expected result"_ that is the result of the function call.

Comment: I don't want the result of function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default CLI, IIRC, uses the standard Node REPL, but does not provide a trivial way to customize it.

You could start your own REPL and provide options as described in the [REPL docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options), specifically focusing on:

- `eval`
- `ignoreUndefined`

The easiest solution is to append something to whatever is returning the long value, e.g., if there's a function called `foo` that returns an object that spans pages, like:

```
> foo()
// countless lines of output
```

Tack on something to the command, like:

```
> foo(); null
null
```